# AJAX request in jquery stops all other Javascript from functioning on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a single AJAX call that is disabling all other javascript from functioning on the page. If I delete the following lines of code, all is well. Am I writing it incorrectly?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/1822727/videos.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('video').each(function(){

      var videoID = $(this).find('id').text();
      var imgURL = $(this).find('thumbnail_large').text();
      $('#galThms').prepend('<li id="' + videoID + '" style="background-image:url(' + imgURL + ');"><a href="#playVideo"></a></li>');

    });
  }
});
```

Comment: what is the error showing in console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The request works too. It just stops the rest of the javascript from functioning correctly.

Comment: So you are able to do that cross domain ajax?? Are you getting success event?

Comment: The success event is running properly, yes.

Comment: what  your remaining javascript do?

Comment: I actually just got it working by adding   crossDomain: true,
 to the ajax array. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Put your remaining javascript too..